# How to Redirect to Login if any http status Unauthorized in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have developed an application using ASP.NET Web API, OAuth Authentication and AngularJS. Once the token invalid/expired its throwing `401 Unauthorized` status. in Angular I have also checked once the http status 401, I redirect it to login state. working perfectly. but I need to create a common/generic object in Angular for all http request, if any http request status 401, it'll automatically redirect to login, no need to check individually for all http request. please see my below code (errorCallback).

**Angular Controller**

```
 StudentServices.GetStudentProfileByPIN($scope.SearchPIN).then(function (response) {
        if (response.data != null) {
            $scope.PInAvailableMsg = "";
        }
        else {
        }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        if (response.status==401) {
            $window.location.href = "/#/login";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS $httpProvider.interceptors allow to modify http request in both way:

1. Before Sending Request
2. After Sending Request

Example: Suppose you have few APIs for your application. Before Calling the API you have to be authorized, otherwise 401 error will be happened, and checking 401 error in all angular controller's object is overwhelming work, but $httpProvider.interceptors will do the common work, once you unauthorized, it'll redirect you to login. just like as constructor for http request. please see the below codes. you can inject it to your app.js

```
mainApp.service('authInterceptor', function ($q, $window) {
  var service = this;
  service.responseError = function (response) {
    if (response.status == 401) {
        $window.location.href = "/#/login";
    }
    return $q.reject(response);
  };
});


mainApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home/home.html'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You can use [Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) . You will have to add them to `app.config`. They will handle all the requests

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$translateProvider', '$windowProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider, $windowProvider) {
    var $window = $windowProvider.$get();
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $location, $localStorage, $window) {
        return {
            request: function(config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                return config;
            },
            response: function(response) {
                if (response.data.code == 401) {
                    $location.path('/signIn');

                }
                return response || $q.when(response);
            }
        };
    });
}]);
```